# django tastypie with non-orm using redis returns no objects

Tags: django, redis, tastypie

I am trying to use tastypie with non-orm using the redis.

I implemented a custom Resource, like suggested on http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/non_orm_data_sources.html

Here is the part of the code:

```
class OrderResource(Resource):
    order_id = fields.CharField(attribute='order_id')
    store_url = fields.CharField(attribute='store_url')
    products = fields.ListField(attribute='products')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Order
        resource_name = 'order'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
        authorization = Authorization()

    def _client(self):
        return redis.Redis('localhost')

    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        kwargs = {}
        if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.order_id
        else:
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.order_id

        return kwargs

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        query = self._client()
        results = list()

        for store_url in query.smembers('store_url'):
            orders_id = query.hgetall('store_url:%s' % store_url)
            for order in orders_id.keys():
                order = Order(store_url=store_url, order_id=order)
                results.append(order)

        return results

    def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Filtering disabled for brevity...
        return self.get_object_list(request)
```

But when I try to retrieve all orders, the json `objects` is empty, even with the `total_count` right.
I checked and the Bundle is right:

```
<Bundle for obj: '<orders.models.Order object at 0x10c6f1e90>' and with data: '{'order_id': u'1', 'store_url': u'test.com', 'products': [u'a', u'b', u'c'], 'resource_uri': None}'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

OBS: I can't use django-nonrel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `object_class` in the `Meta` solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

What is `Order` in your code? With `Resource` you don't need `Meta.queryset`. Try to remove it.

Also, make sure `Order` is serializable. Most probably Tastypie unable to serialize it. Try with simple dictionary objects instead of Order first. Read more about [Serialization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html) and [Dehydration](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=hydrate#the-dehydrate-cycle).

Comment: It also makes sense, but wasnt the problem. The problem was that I forgot to set the `object_class` on Meta